# How do I find the most popular search terms by browser?

Tags: keywords, google-keyword-tool

How do I find the most popular search terms categorized by browser? I tried http://www.google.com/trends/explore, but it doesn't let you filter by browser.

Comment: Why are you looking by browser? The browser if often not a factor for much anymore.

Comment: People who use certain browsers have different interests and levels of sophistication.

Comment: While I think this is true, after-all no little ol'e lady is going to install firefox or chrome and then search knitting, I am not sure how far it goes for keywords when you factor in all users. I am sure there is an effect! Interesting thought. From my experience, I have not seen keyword or log file data sliced and diced this way. Is there a way you can find using a log file analyzer? I use sawmill and it allows me to select any data segment (by browser in this case) and then view anything I want after that.

Answer (score 1):

*Trend information is not detailed niche information*

Google trends is merely an insight on what's trending, Google and most likely all the other search engines do not provide detailed information on niche information such as keyword + browser. They do however provide an insight into country, which can be used to GEO target.

*Why do not they share detailed niche information?*

Well there's many reasons. Firstly nothing is free in this world and gathered data earns Google a lot of money. Because of their Google adwords services, sharing too much information would actually lose them money, a situation would be that people could target a keyword + location + browser and therefor the bidding price would decrease and Google would make less money.

*What about harvesting your own data?*

The best way of finding out who is using what and searching for what is using some kind of analytic on your website and using that data to advantage, but if you wanted to use this information based on browser type with adwords sadly you can't, Google will only let webmasters filter by device type (Tablet, Desktop Computer and Mobile Phone). Google Webmasters can shed some light as well but also note that if a user is logged into Google your analytic or webmaster tools will not display this information because of the SSL.

Comment: Where could I buy it then? I can't harvest my own because my site is not a general purpose search site. People arrive only after searching for specific keywords. You would need a general search portal to gather keywords + browser. Maybe Google would not share, but what about a smaller search engine? Maybe one that installs a toolbar or hijacks the home page?